# Java protected modifier

Tags: java, jls

I have just got weird error which involves protected modifier.

I have following code:

```
package p1;

public class C1 {
    protected void doIt() {}
}


package p2;

public class C2 extends p1.C1 {
    private C1 c1_instance;
    public void doItAgain() {
        c1_instance.doIt(); // wtf!!!!
    }
}
```

I get error, stating that `doIt()` has protected access and can't be accessed! But I am in the sub class and do have and access to `doIt()` method.

Is not it a bug?

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of a class you're extending?

Comment: Why not? That is normal I think. But if opposite thing (parent class creates it's descendant instance) is happening then there is something broken in class design.

Comment: No, I don't think that's normal. If you extend a class, then you ***extend*** the base class, means that `C2` can now do everything that `C1` can (you can directly call `doIt()` from within `C2`, I mean, if it wouldn't be protected)...no need for an instance of `C1`.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about package level access stuff, it doesn't come into play most of the time. However, Bobby is correct; creating an instance of the base class in a subclass is unusual and normally unnecessary.

Comment: I am not creating it, it comes from base class.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, you must be setting c1_instance somewhere or it will be null. Are you doing "c1_instance = (c1_instance) this;"? You need to explain why you don't want to call doIt() directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the impression what `protected` meant "accessible from the same package or from a subclass" but the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2.1) is of course more precise, and explains that in a subclass S of C, "If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S."

So you can only access a `protected` method of the superclass via a reference to the subclass you are calling from, like this:

```
public class C2 extends C1 {
    private C2 c2_other_instance;
    public void doItAgain() {
        c2_other_instance.doIt();
    }
}
```

If you explain why you want to access one instance of the superclass from a different instance of the subclass then someone might be able to suggest a better design. Otherwise you will have to make the method `public` or put the classes in the same package.

Comment: Good clarification. Subtle though - I had to read it a couple of times to fully understand!

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can't call `protected` methods **on a different instance of the base class**, even from within a subclass:

```
public class C2 extends p1.C1 {
    private C1 c1_instance;
    public void doItAgain() {
        doIt();             // fine
        c1_instance.doIt(); // disallowed
    }
}
```

The only exception is when both the base class and the subclass are in the same package.

To quote the [Java OO tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> The `protected` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

Comment: `The only exception is when both the base class and the subclass are in the same package.` Why?

Comment: @misha nesterenko: Simply because this is how the language works. See the tutorial I've linked to in my answer.

Comment: `by a subclass of its class in another package` I don't see any violation of this rule, I am in a subclass of its class in another package.

Comment: That seems to be just obscure documentation, but I would like to know why that restriction is applied?

Comment: @misha nesterenko The statement "by a subclass of its class in another package" means it can be called directly by the subclass, not an instance in the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Protected is equivalent to package level access; you can't access the method if you are in a different package.

You should be able to call doIt() directly without going through the c1_instance object however, as C2 is a subclass.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

"The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package."

Answer (score 1):

C2 may be a sub class of C1, but this does not mean it can access those methods on a different instance, i.e. c1_instance may not be an instance of C2.  You could access it if it was in the same package.

Comment: That's really strange and bad :(. I don't understand why this restriction is applied. If I call from the same package `c1_instance may not be an instance of C2` also.

Answer (score 1):

No, `protected` assures access in the same package and in the descendant classes. You are neither in the same package nor you are accessing it directly from a descendant class. `C2` is a descendant but `c1_instance` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is declared as protected then you can access this within this class , withing the package and within the subclass.

now here is the question , why is there an error inspite of accessing this protected member from its subclass. the answer is to access the protected method from a subclass your subclass should use the method directly from the direct subclass. here the direct subclass is C2 but the instance c1_instance is not. you can use this method directly (doIt() in place of c1_instance.doIt())